# UITableViewController not showing data

Tags: ios, uitableview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [UITableViewController not loading data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12032555/uitableviewcontroller-not-loading-data)

I have created a UITableViewController in the following way

```
#import "KLActionsViewController.h"

@interface KLActionsViewController ()

@end

@implementation KLActionsViewController
@synthesize actionList,delegate;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)loadView
{

}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSMutableArray* list = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] init];
    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    self.actionList = list;
    self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;
    self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(320.0, 400.0);
    [self.actionList addObject:@"Obj1"];
    [self.actionList addObject:@"Obj2"];
    [self.actionList addObject:@"Obj3"];
    [self.actionList addObject:@"Obj4"];

}

- (int)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    NSLog(@"in number of section");
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    NSString* lab = [self.actionList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
//    NSLog(lab);
    NSLog(@"here in there");
    cell.textLabel.text = lab;
    return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"Total entries : %i ",[self.actionList count]);
    return [self.actionList count];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (self.delegate != nil) {
        [self.delegate actionSelected:indexPath.row];
    }
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    self.actionList = nil;
    self.delegate = nil ;
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end
```

But when I try to create it's instance and show it in a `UIPopoverController` all I can see is an empty table and no data in it. Also, `numberOfRowsInSection` and `cellForRowAtIndexPath` never get called.
Any help ?

Comment: try removing that loadView "implementation"

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new table view inside `viewDidLoad:` but not making it a subview of this controller's view.  Since you say you see an empty table, this leads me to believe that you're loading one table from your .xib file, but setting the `dataSource` only of this new one.

If that's how it's structured, use a connection in the .xib from the table view to the `self.tableView` property and don't create a new object...just configure the one you have.

Comment: This is a 'UITableViewController'and I am allocating memory for the tableView that is already a part of it. Do I still need to add it as a subview by doing something like '[self.view addSubview:self.tableView] ? Also I don't have any .xib file. I am trying to show this table only.

Comment: Since you show `initWithNibName:` it suggested **that** was being used.  What's the code look like that creates a `KLActionsViewController`?  If you are creating the view hierarchy in code instead of in a .xib, look at the documentation of the `loadView` method, especially the part where it talks about updating the `view` property.

Comment: This is what I am doing to load it
'vc = [[KLActionsViewController alloc] init];
initWithContentViewController:vc];
actionsController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:vc];
'