# UITableViewController not loading data

Tags: ios, uitableview

So I have created a subclass of `UITableViewController` and set the delegate and datasource to itself. But still the methods like `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and `numberOfRowsInSection` never get called.My `numberOfSectionsInTableView` return 1 everytime.
This is how viewDidLoad() looks like

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
NSMutableArray* list = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] init];
self.tableView.delegate = self;
self.tableView.dataSource = self;
self.actionList = list;
self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;
self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(320.0, 400.0);
[self.actionList addObject:@"t1"];
[self.actionList addObject:@"t2"];
}
```

When I try to load this in a popover all I get is a blank popover.
[image: This is what I see in the UIPopover]

I have spent a lot of time on this. Please help me out.

EDIT: .m file

//  KLActionsViewController.m
    #import "KLActionsViewController.h"

```
@interface KLActionsViewController ()

@end

@implementation KLActionsViewController
@synthesize actionList,delegate;

//- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
//{
//    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
//    if (self) {
//        // Custom initialization
//    }
//    return self;
//}

//- (void)loadView
//{
//    
//}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSMutableArray* list = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320.0, 100.0) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    self.actionList = list;
    self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;
    self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(320.0, 200.0);
    [self.actionList addObject:@"t1"];
    [self.actionList addObject:@"t2"];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    NSLog(@"in number of section");
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    NSString* lab = [self.actionList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
//    NSLog(lab);
    NSLog(@"here in there");
    cell.textLabel.text = lab;
    return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"Total entries : %i ",[self.actionList count]);
    return [self.actionList count];
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (self.delegate != nil) {
        [self.delegate actionSelected:indexPath.row];
    }
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    self.actionList = nil;
    self.delegate = nil ;
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end
```

The .h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol KLActionsViewControllerDelegate
- (void)actionSelected:(NSInteger)index;
@end

@interface KLActionsViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray* actionList;
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<KLActionsViewControllerDelegate> delegate;


@end
```

Comment: In ur .h file have u declared `UITableViewDataSource`. I hv doubt coz in ur code the color of `self.tableview.datasource=self` is not same as `self.tableview.delegate=self` color

Comment: Yes I have done so, Don't know why it is not showing it here.

Comment: Can you please upload codes of your `.h` and `.m` file.

Comment: I have added the same @OhhMee

Comment: did you ever discover the reason?

Comment: No, not really. It must have been something very simple that I am missing because I have designed plenty of these since then with no problems at all.

Comment: Kindly check your hight of TableView. in my case my hight was too much small and in your code i am unable to see hight of the tableViewCell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are extending the `UITableViewController` it already creates `UITableView` instance at viewDidLoad. Try to set a breakpoint there and check it in debugger console:

```
po [self view]
```

Therefore you should not create the `UITableView` instance by yourself at this point. If you need a custom init of the table view you should do it earlier

EDIT

From the documentation:

[About Table Views in iOS-Based Applications](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451)

*The easiest and recommended way to create a table view is to create a custom UITableViewController object. UITableViewController creates the table view and assigns itself as delegate and data source.*

[Creating a Table View Programmatically](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/CreateConfigureTableView/CreateConfigureTableView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH6-SW2)

*If you choose not to use UITableViewController for table-view management, you must replicate what this class gives you “for free.”*

```
- (void)loadView // <-- NOT VIEW DID LOAD!
{
    UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]
                                  style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    tableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    tableView.delegate = self;
    tableView.dataSource = self;
    [tableView reloadData];

    self.view = tableView;
    [tableView release];
}
```

Comment: I don't think it allocates memory to it. So i tried the part of allocating memory to it to `viewDidLoad` , still no respite....

Comment: Use the debugger, read the documentation, and don't think too much ;-)

Comment: I think you probably want to include a call to [super loadView] as well.

Comment: @haggleLad you do not need to ask super to load view if you are initializing the view manually

Comment: Fair enough, but I'm not using a XIB and my app crashes without a [super loadView] call.

Comment: @HaggleLad You should pay attentions to the details. Look at this tutorial "Create and Configure a Table View": https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/CreateConfigureTableView/CreateConfigureTableView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH6-SW4

Comment: @voromax, I've re-investigated the code in question and you are absolutely correct. In my instance, the reason I needed to call [super loadView] was because there was code that read the frame size of self.view which wouldn't have existed without a [super loadView] call.  Regardless I found the documentation that clearly states you shouldn't really be calling [super loadView] here  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/loadView

Answer (score 0):

Try adding [self.tableView reloadData] at the end of the viewDidLoad

Comment: Tried, doesn't make a difference. The mentioned methods still don't get called

Answer (score 0):

In .h file, add  `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource`

Something like this:

```
@interface Yourclass : rootClass <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one in .h file

```
@interface KLActionsViewController:UIView <UITableViewDelegate,UItableViewDataSource>
```