# ios6 - numberOfRowsInSection doesn't run for custom tableviewcell, delegate/datasource set

Tags: ios, ios6, uitableview

I have a custom view EMViewController with a tableview as a subview.  I want EMViewController to double as the controller for the subview, so I have it set as the delegate and dataSource.

```
// EMViewController.h
@interface EMViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
...
// EMViewController.m
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.eTableView.delegate = self;
    self.eTableView.dataSource = self;
}
```

I'm populating the data with an asynchronous array/dictionary from Facebook, so once I have the data, I run

```
[self.eTableView reloadData]
```

For the UITableViewDataSource protocol methods, I implemented the following:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    NSLog(@"returns sections 0"); // This appears in my log
    return 0;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSLog(@"returning count %d", [self.eList count]); // never shows up
    return [self.eList count];
}

- (EMTableViewCell *)tableView:(EMTableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // configure the cell
    NSLog(@"index: %d", indexPath); // never shows up
    ...
}
```

So far, I have already tried:

- making sure my storyboard is connected up
- checking/rechecking the delegate/dataSource being set in viewDidLoad
- completely restarting/clean-building my app just in case
- creating a placeholder UIView subclass (although I'm not changing much)
- creating a customUITableViewCell class with outlets for my custom layout (images, 3 labels)
- testing out strong/weak references to the tableView outlet

Any advice would be appreciated. I think my problem is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12032555/uitableviewcontroller-not-loading-data), except I'm trying to add the tableview as a subview.  My end goal is to populate the cells with a custom format that includes an image and three labels.  Thanks!

Comment: Please show dequence code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return 1 section instead of returning 0 sections

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Or, just don't implement that method at all. The default is 1.

Comment: silly meeeeee.  i thought the comments in the auto-generated stub say returning 0 is the default for 1 section.  As a followup, how do I access the storyboard elements I built for the prototype cell?